# string parameter passing not working in django1.9

Tags: python, django

I am passing a string parameter in view but its not working.

```
url(r'^users/(?P<user_type>\w+)/$', views.users, name='users'),
url(r'^users/$', views.users, name='users')
```

**view is:-**

```
def users(request, user_type=None):
```

**Link is:-**

```
<a href="{% url 'users' %}">All Users</a>
<a href="{% url 'users' customers %}">Customers</a>
<a href="{% url 'users' promoters %}">Promoters</a>
```

But its giving error when i access view without parameter

```
Reverse for 'users' with arguments '('',)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 2 pattern(s) tried: ['administrator/users/$', 'administrator/users/(?P<user_type>\\w+)/$']

Exception Value: Reverse for 'users' with arguments '('',)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 2 pattern(s) tried: ['administrator/users/$', 'administrator/users/(?P<user_type>\\w+)/$']
```

Comment: pls give a different name for both

Comment: for both means in url ?

Comment: ya.. for the second url, give name as `user` or something you want..

Comment: Still same error, have i also change its in links ?

Comment: ya.. you have to..

Comment: done, its working now thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this and check

```
url(r'^users/(?P<user_type>\w+)/$', views.users, name='users_type'),
url(r'^users/$', views.users, name='users')
```

Link is:

```html
<a href="{% url 'users' %}">All Users</a>
<a href="{% url 'users_type' "customers" %}">Customers</a>
<a href="{% url 'users_type' "promoters" %}">Promoters</a>
```